# Split on comma, but only when not in parenthesis

Tags: perl, split

I am trying to do a split on a string with comma delimiter

```
my $string='ab,12,20100401,xyz(A,B)';
my @array=split(',',$string);
```

If I do a split as above the array will have values

```
ab
12
20100401
xyz(A,
B)
```

I need values as below.

```
ab
12
20100401
xyz(A,B)
```

(should not split xyz(A,B) into 2 values)
How do I do that?

Comment: One way: process the string and change `(A,B)` to something else, e.g. `(A\,B)`, then change it back after splitting.

Comment: This question isn't fully specified; how do you tell the difference between the comma between A and B and the other commas?  (Typically quoting or some an escaping mechanism is used in CSV to avoid the ambiguity.)

Comment: Balanced parentheses are pretty similar to pairs of quotes.  If you want to ignore commas inside balanced parentheses (quotes), you normally need something more powerful than just a regular expression.  I believe the Perl 6 regexes may have some of the necessary support.

Comment: This looks more like a job for tokenizing than a simple split

Answer (score 4):

```
use Text::Balanced qw(extract_bracketed);
my $string = "ab,12,20100401,xyz(A,B(a,d))";
my @params = ();
while ($string) {
    if ($string =~ /^([^(]*?),/) {
        push @params, $1;
        $string =~ s/^\Q$1\E\s*,?\s*//;
    } else {
        my ($ext, $pre);
        ($ext, $string, $pre) = extract_bracketed($string,'()','[^()]+');
        push @params, "$pre$ext";
        $string =~ s/^\s*,\s*//;
    }
}
```

This one supports:

- nested parentheses;
- empty fields;
- strings of any length.

Comment: This is a nice attempt, but not that the code will enter infinite loop if the parentheses are not balanced. E.g. `$string = "ab,12,20100401,xyz(A,B,(a,d)"`

Comment: String should validated before being parsed.

Comment: This goes into an infinite loop unless the last item contains -- and ends with -- a parenthetical phrase. `d,e` fails, `d(e),f` fails, `c, d(e) f` fails.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way that should work.

```
use Regexp::Common;

my $string = 'ab,12,20100401,xyz(A,B)';
my @array = ($string =~ /(?:$RE{balanced}{-parens=>'()'}|[^,])+/g);
```

[Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2010010201/lib/Regexp/Common.pm) can be installed from CPAN.

There is a bug in this code, coming from the depths of Regexp::Common.  Be warned that this will (unfortunately) fail to match the lack of space between `,,`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, old question, but I just happened to wrestle with this all night, and the question was never marked answered, so in case anyone arrives here by Google as I did, here's what I finally got. It's a very short answer using only built-in PERL regex features:

```
my $string='ab,12,20100401,xyz(A,B)';
$string =~ s/((\((?>[^)(]*(?2)?)*\))|[^,()]*)(*SKIP),/$1\n/g;
my @array=split('\n',$string);
```

Commas that are not inside parentheses are changed to newlines and then the array is split on them. This will ignore commas inside any level of nested parentheses, as long as they're properly balanced with a matching number of open and close parens.

This assumes you won't have newline `\n` characters in the initial value of $string. If you need to, either temporarily replace them with something else before the substitution line and then use a loop to replace back after the `split`, or just pick a different delimiter to split the array on.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the number of elements it can be split into:

```
split(',', $string, 4)
```

Comment: What happens if the balanced parens are in the third field?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
my $string='ab,12,20100401,xyz(A,B)';
my @array = ($string =~ /(
    [^,]*\([^)]*\)   # comma inside parens is part of the word
    |
    [^,]*)           # split on comma outside parens
    (?:,|$)/gx);
```

Produces:

```
ab
12
20100401
xyz(A,B)
```

Comment: What if the string contained "foo,xyz(A(B,C),D),bar"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. It should handle depth well and could even be extended to include other bracketed symbols easily (though harder to be sure that they MATCH). This method will not in general work for quotation marks rather than brackets.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string='ab,12,20100401,xyz(A(2,3),B)';

print "$_\n" for parse($string);

sub parse {
  my ($string) = @_;
  my @fields;

  my @comma_separated = split(/,/, $string);

  my @to_be_joined;
  my $depth = 0;
  foreach my $field (@comma_separated) {
    my @brackets = $field =~ /(\(|\))/g;
    foreach (@brackets) {
      $depth++ if /\(/;
      $depth-- if /\)/;
    }

    if ($depth == 0) {
      push @fields, join(",", @to_be_joined, $field);
      @to_be_joined = ();
    } else {
      push @to_be_joined, $field;
    }
  }

  return @fields;
}
```